# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0]

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Trying to build a react native project, and cannot compile appcompat

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

**UPDATE**
changing to implementation yields

```
ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]Use implementation rather than compile.
Compile is now depricated for gradle file.

implementation use Against compile.

testImplementation use Against  testcompile.

runtimeOnly use Against runtime.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

**These line will not enter in build.gradle(Project:Projectname)** 
These lines will be under **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waltonbd.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/raw'] } }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Another one is **build.gradle(Project:Projectname)**. Don't enter here.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: There are 2 build.gradle file .One is for (Project: projectname) .Second is for (Module.app).

Answer (score 4):

The `compile` keyword in gradle has been deprecated, replace with `implementation` instead.

Comment: tried with implementation instead ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `compile` with `implementation`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

The `compile` method was deprecated: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

> The compile, testCompile, runtime and testRuntime configurations inherited from the Java plugin are still available but are deprecated. You should avoid using them, as they are only kept for backwards compatibility.

It is possible that they are now actually removed from the version of gradle you are using.

Comment: tried and ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Top-level build.gradle file is the wrong place for dependencies. It's even stated in a comment in your code:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

You should move these lines to another build.gradle file (in your module)

Comment: thanks, where to place them, I'm a complete noob sorry

Comment: I'm trying to build a react-native app, so I'm not aware of how gradle works

Comment: @OmarS. to another build.gradle file, in Android projects it is located somewhere like `app/build.gradle`. Don't know about React Native

Comment: yes this is app/build.gradle, shall I create another file, and where to place it, and what should be the name if so

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has this problem with the third-party `build.gradle`, you can use `patch-package` to do a patch for the fix.