# Can't run the project after installing react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

After adding the react-native-video to the newly created project I get this error when I want to run the project (android), but once I uninstall it, everything runs ok.

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\android\build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myTestApp'.      
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-video'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\android\build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myTestApp'.      
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-video'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

    at makeError (C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\myTestApp\myTestApp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

**I add react-native-video to my project according to the documentation.**

```
   npm install --save react-native-video
   cd myTestApp
   npm run android
```

then when I run the project I got the above error

Comment: Looks like you added the **compile('react-native-video')** in your **android/build.gradle** instead of **android/app/build.gradle** file.

Comment: Thanks, Akshay, but I am still having the same issue after I added compile('react-native-video') to android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Replace compile project(':react-native-video') to **implementation project(':react-native-video')**

[Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594801/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-com-android-supportappcompat-v7)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](https://giters.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2553).

Go to file: node_module/react-native-video/android-exoplayer/build.gradle

change all references of 2.13.2 to 2.13.3

Comment: Just wanted to know, isn't node_modules something which should not be edited? Since a new npm command will remove the changes you have done? Unless you clone the npm module in your code?